# How can I extract string using Php regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have string like `<p>{{name}}</p>`
and I tried below code:

```
$subject="<p>{{name}}</p>";
$pattern="/(\[\[|<p>{{)\w+(]]|}}</p>)/";

$success = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);
if ($success) {
    $str = substr($match[0], 5,-2);
    echo $str;
} else {
         echo 'not match';
    }
```

How can I extract `name` value using regex function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for name between a `<p>` tags and double opening and closing curly braces {{ }}, you could also do it like this:

[`<p>{{\K.+?(?=}}<\/p>)`](https://regex101.com/r/pDsGRa/1)

**Explanation**

- Match `<p>{{`
- Reset the starting point of the reported match `\K`
- Match any character one or more times (this will be the value you are looking for)
- A positive lookahead `(?=}}<\/p>)` which asserts that what follows is `}}</p>`

You can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all of the matches, or use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to return the first match.

[Output](https://3v4l.org/Q8NH0)

Your code could look like:

```
$subject="<p>{{name}}</p>";
$pattern="/<p>{{\K.+?(?=}}<\/p>)/";

$success = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);
if ($success) {
    $str = substr($match[0], 5,-2);
    echo $str;
} else {
    echo 'not match';
}
```

Note that `$str` will be `false` in this case using [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try using a pattern with a capture group which isolates the name you want:

```
subject="<p>{{name}}</p>";
$pattern="/<p>\{\{([^}]+)\}\}<\/p>/";

$success = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);
if ($success) {
    echo $match[1];
} else {
     echo 'not match';
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

No need to check `p` tag as you want only text inside `{{...}}`.If you want to get all value inside `{{..}}` try `preg_match_all` like this

```
<?php
$subject="<p>name is {{name}} and age is {{age}}</p>";
preg_match_all('#\{\{(.*?)\}\}#', $subject, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/929064

You will get array of values inside `{{...}}`

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => age
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strip_tags](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp) and then **preg_replace**

```
$subject="<p>{{name}}</p>";
$pattern="/[^a-zA-Z]/";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "", strip_tags($subject));
```

> Output will be **name**